# I have no fonts in Java?

Tags: java, fonts

I have tried `GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getAllFonts()` and also `Font.getFont(String name)` but they always return null or empty. Why?

EDIT: This is in eclipse, but using Greenfoot I can get fonts just fine. OS: MacOS 10.6.8 Java: 6

Comment: OS?  Version?  How are you launching the VM?

Comment: Works just fine for me in Eclipse Indigo (20110615-0604), Java SE 6 64 bit (1.6.0_29-b11-402), Max OS X 10.7.2. Please post your VM, version of Eclipse, and JDK.

Comment: I think I will update java again to see what that does.

Answer (score 0):

On Mac OS X 10.7 using Java 6, this code for me returns a long list for fonts:

```
public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
    final Font[] allFonts = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getAllFonts();
    for (Font font : allFonts) {
        System.out.println("font = " + font);
    }
}
```

If you copy and paste that into your computer what do you get?

If you get no fonts still, you should report it to the apple java mailing list (https://lists.apple.com/mailman/listinfo/java-dev)

Comment: Odd, that returned something.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found out what went wrong. I had been checking by `System.out.println(allFonts);` and that printed empty, but when i print individual ones like Steve said, it prints fine. My question is, why does this not happen with other arrays I have?

Comment: That isn't a method. Arrays.toString(Object[] o) is.